# Insert data to database in foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I have "competitions" and i want all of them to have a "join" button, once its pressed some date goes into a database.. ex:comp1
I've displayed the comp info in a page.
Code:

```xml
@foreach ($users as $comp)
  <div class="card" style="width: 300px;">
    <img src="{{url('/comp/')}}/{{ $comp->CompID }}.jpg" class="w-100">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ $comp->CompName }}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Ending: {{ $comp->EndDate }}</p>
      <p class="card-text">Pot: {{ $comp->Pot }}</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Join</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  @if ($loop->iteration % 3 == 0)
    </div>
    <div class="row pt-2 justify-content-center">
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your anchor tag with a button, attach an even listener to it and call an endpoint to manipulate the database.

```xml
<button class="btn btn-primary join" type="button" data-id="{{ $comp->CompID }}">Join</button>
```

```js
$(() => {
    $('.join').on('click', e => {
        let compId = $(e.currentTarget).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: ...,
            data: ...,
            method: ...
        })
        .then(result => ...)
        .catch(error => ...)
        .always(() => ...);
    });
});
```